# Kubernetes Pod stuck on "Pending State": "error: watch closed before Until timeout"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using Jenkins to re-deploy a Kubernetes deployment.  Unfortunately, when deploying my Pod stays in a perpetual "Pending State" -- where the pod is not "Ready", but still creating.  I can see the logs and can see that the new version of my code is running just fine, with no errors, but my pod is still labeled as "Pending".

I've also looked at the Jenkins logs, which hold this as a possible culprit:

```
error: watch closed before Until timeout
```

I'm not sure what a "watch" is.  What went wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide output of `kubectl describe pod <pending-pod-name>`  and `kubectl logs <pending-pod-name>`

Comment: Apparently, this is a known issue and it has been fixed already - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/50102

Comment: I faced the same with Gitlab 12.4 and OpenShift (3.11 on Kubernates v1.11).